# Azure DevOps Server register an application

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps server on-premises and I have written a small application that simply queries its API to get information from the Azure server. There is no authentication at the user level, since the application only displays information and does not POST/PUT/DELETE.

To query the API, I have used my PAT (personal access token), but this is not ideal. I have read that on the cloud version of Azure, you can just register the application to do it, but I have not found the same functionality for the on-premises version.

Am I missing something? Is the only alternative creating a technical user on the LDAP and get a PAT for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the only alternative creating a technical user on the LDAP and get
> a PAT for it?

Yes, you are right.

[Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-2022)

[image]

**So 'App auth' is only supported in Azure DevOps Services (VSTS), not supported in Azure DevOps server (TFS).**